# Kendo grid - bind to remote data from three web services

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to build a single kendo grid from three web services (by obtaining final data after combining all three web services)? I am using asp.net web forms not MVC.

Comment: Yes, it is possible! :-)

Comment: Can you please provide an example...where I can combine three web services and load into grid....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but you should not do it in the client Kendo UI `DataSource` but in the server. The reasons are:

1. There is a lot of code to implement if you do it in client.
2. Doing it simple requires reading the sources sequentially.
3. Reading sources in parallel requires a lot of code for dealing with the different reading and transfer times.
4. You have to mix the results of the different data sets.
5. This works for reading but updating and deleting is much (Much, MUCH) code.
6. Reading from a DB multiple DataSource uses to be as simple as a JOIN.

If despite of data you still want it, try defining a DataSource for each of the different DataSource and a fourth one for the composition of the other three.

When the `read` operation of the *composed* datasource is invoked, invoke a `fetch` on the first of the three separate DataSources, in the fetch function handler of this, invoke a `fetch` for the second and in the fetch of the third, create the merge of the three data received.

```
// First datasource
var ds1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    ...
});
// Second datasource
var ds2 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    ...
});
// Third datasource
var ds3 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    ...
});
// Composed
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
   transport: {
        read: function (op) {
             ds1.fetch(function () {
                 ds2.fetch(function () {
                     ds3.fetch(function () {
                         // Merge data from ds1, ds2 and ds3 in data
                         ... 
                         // Invoke success
                         op.success(data);
                     });
                 });
             });
        }
   }
   ...
}
```